# Getting a File's Last Modified Date

Tags: android

I'm using this to see if a file already exists and get its timestamp:

```
File file = new File(getResources().getString(R.string.file_name));

if (file.exists()) {
  Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
}
```

Even though I can see that this file does indeed exist using the Context.fileList() method, the code above always says it doesn't.

How can I get a file's last modified date?

Comment: What's your issue here? That file.exists() fails?

Comment: file.exists() is returning false.  Whenever I call file.lastModified() it returns zero.  The file name string is just a name like "myfile.txt" without any path information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I take it your problem is that `file.exists()` fails, the issue with the modified date has nothing to do with it.

I'd venture that the path you're using is local to your application? You'll need to use absolute paths when using `File`.

Comment: It was indeed a path problem.  The solution was to use Context.getFileStreamPath(fileName) to get the File object.  Then the file.exists() and file.lastModified() methods worked fine.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Glad to help! This pathing thing is a common pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the path

if u send invalid path then u will always get 0 or the 1970 something! (because the Google set The start Date to that date :) )

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/file1.jpg");
```

Comment: It was actually not "the Google" who set that date but rather the nature of how unix timestamps are made - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time